# Apply data cleaning date function to each row in column

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I am trying to clean 'messy' dates and convert them to a day-month-year format via a function. I've tested my function and it produces the correct results.

```
def date_change(strDate):
    if ("-") in strDate:
        sp_Str_Dob= strDate.split("-")
    elif ("/") in strDate:
        sp_Str_Dob= strDate.split("/")

    if len(strDate)==4:
        return (strDate)
#day processing
    length_Day= len(sp_Str_Dob[0])
    if length_Day ==1:
        new_Day= str(("0" + sp_Str_Dob[0]))
    else:
        new_Day= str(sp_Str_Dob[0])
#month processing
    strMonth= (sp_Str_Dob[1])
    if (len(strMonth)) ==3:
        new_Month= str((strptime(strMonth,'%b').tm_mon)) #change letter month to number
    else:
        new_Month= str((strptime(strMonth,'%m').tm_mon)) #month is number
#year processing
    strYear= (sp_Str_Dob[2])
    length_Year= len(sp_Str_Dob[2])
    if length_Year ==2: #if only two digits then 20th cemtury
       new_Year= str("19" + sp_Str_Dob[2])
    else:
        new_Year= str(sp_Str_Dob[2]) 

    new_Date_Str= (new_Day + "/" + new_Month + "/" + new_Year)
    print(new_Date_Str)
```

Currently if input is:

- 30-Sep-1895
- 22-Mar-76
- 14/08/1966

The output would be

- 30/9/1895
- 22/3/1976
- 14/8/1966

I'm trying to go through a column ['dob'] in my subset, which will replace old values to new_Date_Str

```
subset:

    dob
ID
1   30-Sep-1895
2   22-Mar-76
3   14/08/1966
```

I would have to change the function so it called no arguments and go through each value in ['dob'] in my function, however, I'm a bit confused on how to do go through each row without using iterrows/tuples as it is discouraged.

Is .loc the best way to do this?

Update:
Any year ending in two digits should be converted to a 20th century year.

Answer (score 3):

Pandas `to_datetime` can handle date time in different formats, it will return dates in in month first format. You can use `strftime` to convert these to day-first but the date will be object type, not `datetime`.

```
df['dob'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dob']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

    dob
ID  
1   30/09/1895
2   22/03/1976
3   14/08/1966
```

Comment: Beat me to it, by a second +1

Comment: @U9-Forward, happens all the time :)

Comment: Lol :-) people said that to me before too :-)

Comment: Thanks @Vaishali 
Though the column now contains the correct format, I'm getting a SettingWithCopyWarning

Comment: Did you create this dataframe from another one by copying the columns? That should be the only reason to get SettingWithCopyWarning

Comment: @Vaishali
After running the function 
For inputs:
 26-Jul-22, 
 31-Aug-28, 
 05-Aug-06

 I get the outputs:
 26/07/2022, 
 31/08/2028, 
 05/08/2006

Comment: Shouldnt that be the output for 26-Jul-22, 31-Aug-28, 05-Aug-06?

Comment: So 05-Aug-06 should be 05/08/1906?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190919/discussion-between-hawwa-and-vaishali).